# open SAS risk file extension of .rskcdesc

Tags: java, python, sas, risk-analysis

In my project which deals with SAS 
we have risk binary files of extension .rskcdesc

I have been looking but not able to find any python Java library which can read it.
 I need to automate data checks via Backend process, hence need a way to decode these files.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Rohit,

I don't have SAS Risk but SAS has been using zip for some of their files (like EG projects). Try renaming the file extension to .zip and open it. It may be comprised of XML files, similar to EG.

Comment: Bummer. Some other options (not good, but tossing out) are that they are 1) sas7cat files, 2) sas7bdat files. If you have SAS installed, you can try renaming the extension to one of those 2 and seeing if either one opens in SAS. If you have safe version (no secure info), you can post it here and I can look at it in 010 Editor and help determine the file type.